# Hiding Tabbar still occupy Space?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am creating a navigation base application. I need to display a tab bar too.

My mainWindow.xib contains:

- `UINavigationController`,
- `UITabBarController`.

`UITabBarController` has three `UINavigationController` with it.

On a condition-based algorithm, I am displaying the Navigation and the TabBar.

It's working well. The problem occurs when I want to move any inner view of TabBar: it shows navigationBar there (what I need) but it shows TabBar too. I want to remove the TabBar of all inner view. When I hide the tabbar it still occupy its space at the bottom of view. I had tried to reset frame of View and Window but nothing helped.

How can I hide tabBar and use its space in my view?

Is the logic I am using correct or not? If not, please tell how to correct it. If there is a tutorial it would be better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
yourInnerViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourInnerViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: That's what exactly I was lloking for.. Thanks @sycx. Please let me know that this approach is not prohibited by apple. Thanks

Comment: Don't worried,this is a general usage ,introduce in View Controller Programming Guide

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem in swift. how do you do that in Swift?

Comment: I'm using `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true' and 'self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed =  true' in my viewWillAppear to hide the tabbar. It works most of the time, But not all the time.  Also, It's not very smooth. Everytime the ViewController presents itself, the white space on the bottom where tabbasr used to be takes a while to disappear.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that you can't and trying to force it will break apple's HIG and they'll most probably reject your app.

The way I got around it was to use `[self presentModalViewController:animated:]` instead of `[self.navigationController pushViewController:animated:]`.

I know its annoying, but a tab bar controller is there to switch between sections of your app. Therefore it provides functionality outside of the context of the navigation controllers within it and therefore cannot be hidden (properly) from inside one of those navigation controllers.

Comment: Thanks Thomas but using presentModalViewController I can't use navigation controller too.

Comment: using presentModalViewController you can pass in a new navigation controller.

Comment: so what is the purpose of `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true`